# photoshop coloring with an outline, refine edge

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, mask, outline

n photoshop I imported the black outline of a character for coloring. I want to create a quick mask so that I can't color outside the character's outer perimeter. Since the character's outline is black, this seemed like a simple issue- quick select outside the figure and use the quick selection to make a mask on a layer under the outline, then color on the lower layer. This worked... okay... but I think there's a way to refine my edge edge better but I can't think of how. The issue is that the mask allows me to color a few pixels out from the edge. It's better than no mask at all and I can just erase but- I remember there being a way to move the edge just a few pixels when making a selection- just don't remember what control does that. Anyone remember this control? I think it's under "refine edge"

Answer (score 1):

From the menu with an active selection....

`Select > Modify > Expand` 
or 
`Select > Modify > Contract`